# Minimum file structures needed for Nextjs on production

Tags: build, next.js, production

I'm struggling to understand the correct way or BEST WAY to deploy nextjs app.
I have a hybrid Nextjs website which I currently host on Azure App Service.
So far I run

- npm build
- npm start
  The app compile with no error and I host on Azure all the content of my application which contains
- .next/
- components/
- pages/
- ...all configs
- ..all js files

Looking from Nextjs documentation (which is kind of slim on this topic), seems that this is the right way to do it.
From my understanding tho, just the `.next/` folder should be needed for production, since is the one that has bundled code. The `pages/`, `components/` and so on, should be used just on development mode.

I also found some other examples online that go in this direction.
If i try to remove /pages or /components tho, I got error and the app cannot run any more.

Can someone confirm me what is the minimum file structures needed for Nextjs application on production?

UPDATE:

The error I get is first:
`ENOENT: no such file or directory, i18n`

When I add this file, then I get the error:

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, pages/`

`i18n.js` is a configuration file for the packages `next-tralsation`
https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate

I'm talking with the author there as well, it might be a problem on their end, but right now I just want to know if na hybrid Nextjs.js app in production should include `pages/` folder.
I want to know if `.next/` folder is enough for production deployment and if not, i would like to understand why.

Comment: Could you post what error are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an example of usage with Docker in official repo https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile
But I guess it applies for non-docker environments too.

Basically, it builds application and only keeps this files and folders after that:

- package.json
- next.config.js
- .env*
- public
- .next
- node_modules

So no, `pages` should not be needed after build for vanilla NextJs app, but it might be needed for something else maybe, like `next-translate` package in your example, I am not quite sure how it using `pages` and what for.

Comment: Thank you @Danila this is excatly the confirmation i was looking for!

Comment: So, does next-translate require the pages directory or it's some kind of the wrong configuration?

Comment: The example page doesn't exist any longer. I guess the example can be found here -> https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples